# Can Python's doctest output be parsed by Bamboo's JUnit parser?

Tags: python, xml, junit, bamboo, doctest

I am interested in running a Python project's doctests as part of a Bamboo build. Is there a way to configure doctest to output xml files which are parse-able by JUnit?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's a way to do this with `doctest` itself.

If you run doctests via a test runner like [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/) these tools have an option to return test output as junit XML.

- Nose:

  - [Xunit plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/xunit.html)
  - [Doctest plugin](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/doctests.html)
- py.test:

  - [the --junitxml option](https://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#creating-junitxml-format-files)
  - [doctest support in py.test](https://pytest.org/latest/doctest.html)

Answer (score 0):

Steven's advice was correct - nose is the way to go. Here's the code to do it:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import nose

    # First argument is a dummy
    # --with-doctest enables parsing the doctests
    # --with-xunit and --xunit-file generate output files compatible with a JUnit parser (i.e. for Bamboo)
    # The last argument is the name of the file to run tests on
    argv = ["", "--with-doctest", "--with-xunit", "--xunit-file=" + __file__ + ".xml", __file__]
    nose.run(argv=argv)
```